# Using forloop to create dynamic javascript Object

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, jinja2

## Edited Question

Hi all, I want to use forloop to generate a dynamic javascript object, but I am new to js.
I have a `var citymap` which contains `id, latitude, longitude`
I need to generate the values from my database through `flask`
I figured out how to dump it to JSON and read it in `HTML <script>`, my only problem now is how to generate it into a javascript object.
Can I do this inside Python first then dump it to HTML template and read it using template engine with `{{ var }}`
Or this can be done inside

#### My python flask code right now

```
@app.route("/engineer", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def engineer():
    with DatabaseUtils() as db:
        position = db.getFaultyCar()
        token = len(position)
        data = json.dumps(position)
        print(data)
    return render_template("engineer.html", token=token, position=position,data = data)
```

#### My jinja2 HTML template

```
<body>
      <!-- For testing output -->
      <p id="demo"></p>
    <div>
       <!-- Using template to print, but does not work inside js object -->
        {%for car in position%}
        {{ car[0] | tojson }}: {
            center: {lat: {{ car[9] | tojson }}, lng: {{ car[10] | tojson }}}
        },
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
      <div id="map"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        data = JSON.parse({{ data | tojson }});
        var leng = {{ token }};

        var id = [];
        var la= [];
        var lo = [];
        for(i = 0; i < leng; i++){
            id.push(data[i][0]); #id sits at index 0
            la.push(data[i][9]); # latitude sits at index 9
            lo.push(data[i][10]); # longitude sits at index 10
        }

        var x = "";
        for(i = 0; i < leng; i++){
            x += "{" + id[i] + ": { center: {lat: " +  la[i] + ", lng:" + lo[i] + "}},";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

        // Correct format from google doc
        var citymap = {
          14: {
            center: {lat: -37.911012, lng: 144.742922}
          },
          2: {
            center: {lat: -37.823, lng: 144.997}
          },
          3: {
            center: {lat: -37.850, lng: 144.999}
          }
        };
```

#### What the websitelooks like right now

[image]

#### What I planned/wanted is something like this

```
        var y = {};
        for(i = 0; i < leng; i++){
            # Append x value to object y
            y.assign("{" + id[i] + ": { center: {lat: " +  la[i] + ", lng:" + lo[i] + "}},");
        }

        // create citymap with values in y
        var citymap = {
          y
        };

        var citymap = y;
```

Comment: The 3 attributes index of each database row I want to retrieve are [ 0 ], [ 9 ], [ 10 ] 
As you can see I can do it with jinja2 template forloop outside ```<script>```

Comment: tried to use jinja2 template forloop inside ```var citymap = { }``` , but failed....

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I am so stupid.......
What I did was using a forloop from template engine to replace the JS loop, adding the index 9 and 10 representing as latitude and longitude from my database data.

```
           {%for car in position%}
            // Add the circle for this city to the map.
            var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              fillColor: '#FF0000',
              fillOpacity: 0.35,
              map: map,
              center: {lat: {{ car[9] }}, lng: {{ car[10] }}},
              radius: 100
            });
          {% endfor %}
```